# HOW TO SOLVE A GESTURE EXCEPTION IN FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am new to flutter , I am trying to build a to-do app but I have been stuck here for a while
here is my full code so far  : this is the main :

```dart
main() {
  runApp(Myapp());
}

class Myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return homepage();
  }
}
```

and here is my homepage :

```dart
class homepage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      homepagestate createState() => homepagestate();
    }
    
    class homepagestate extends State<homepage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: SafeArea(
                child: Scaffold(
                    body: Container(
          color: Color(0xFFF6F6F6),
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32, horizontal: 24),
          child: Stack(children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.0, bottom: 32.0),
                    child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'))),
                Expanded(
                    child: ListView(children: [
                  taskcardwidget(
                    title: ' get started!',
                    desc:
                        'hello user ! , Welcome to our TO_DO_APP ,  this is a default task that you can edit or delete .',
                  ),
                  taskcardwidget(),
                  taskcardwidget(),
                  taskcardwidget(),
                  taskcardwidget(),
                  taskcardwidget()
                ]))
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
                bottom: 24.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Task()));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                        width: 60,
                        height: 60,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFF7349FE),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/images/add_icon.png'),
                        )))),
          ]),
        ))));
      }
    }
```

and this is the task class  :

```dart
class Task extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TaskState createState() => TaskState();
}

class TaskState extends State<Task> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: Text("hello"),
    ));
  }
}
```

the error is this  :

> Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
> The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
> Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget

Answer (score 0):

Move `MaterialApp` on `Myapp` widget. This will separate the context for `MaterialApp` and able to navigate.

```dart
class Myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  const Myapp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: homepage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Another solution with discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69479178/10157127) .

Comment: I did that ,  and it changed the type of exception , but instead of the old one , I am getting this now : SafeArea widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor. one of the solutions is to wrap it with MaterialApp but that wont work for my situation

Comment: does everything work after removing `SafeArea`?

Comment: NO , the program stops at this line: {  Navigator.push(
                      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Task()));
                }, }

Comment: I Was able to solve it using Routes in the MaterialApp widget , still not sure about what dis cause the problem , Thanks anyway.